# Microsoft OAuth 2.0 Authorize endpoint complains about missing secret

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create an [online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with a web application using the Microsoft Graph API.

When I try to initiate an authorization request to get permissions from the end-user to create a token with a similar URL to:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?state=xxx&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=xxx
```

I get the following error message from the Microsoft API:

> The client does not have a secret configured. If you are the client
> application developer, configure a secret through the application
> management site at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

I have a secret configured for the application in the "Certificates & secrets" part under the "Client secrets":

[image: Client secrets screenshots]

I have no clue what I am missing here and the Microsoft documentation is not really helpful.

Comment: Are you use Microsoft personal account to login? the login.live.com makes me think that way. Per online meeting doc you provide, delegate to personal account is not supported, only work or school account, and the login url look like this: https://login.microsoftonline.com//{tenant}

Comment: I am planning to use the Application permission type. That should support `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All*` permissions according to the doc.

Comment: I believe you will be right. It will be delegated permissions.

Comment: changing the auth url  to login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}  - did this resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the `authorize` and `token` endpoint to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token` respectively as it is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints).

In my case - since I want to support multiple tenants - I could not fill out the `{tenant}` part of the URL with the actual tenant id, but I needed to set `organizations` since as it is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) only work or school accounts are supported.

So the final URLs changed to the following:

- Authorize: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
- Token: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token`